# how to solve the error:Warning messages: package ‘ ’ was built under R version 3.3.3

Tags: r, installation, package

I use R3.3.2. when I want to install the package "arules" , I get this error:

```
install.packages("arules")

Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

Restarting R session...

Loading required package: arules
Loading required package: Matrix

Attaching package: ‘arules’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

abbreviate, write

Loading required package: twitteR
Loading required package: wavelets
> install.packages("arules")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
Warning messages:
1: package ‘arules’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
2 : package ‘twitteR’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
> install.packages("arules")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Atapour/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘arules’ is in use and will not be installed
```

whenever I atempt to install the "arules" , "matrix" ,"twitteR" , "FactoMineR" and so on, I get the error of :e.g. package ‘twitteR’ was built under R version 3.3.3

I try downloading from cran site(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FactoMineR/index.html) but doest'nt help me anymore.
what should I do to fix it?

Comment: why do you want this to be fixed? this is just a warning (as it says there) which can usually be ignored.

Comment: And if you really want to fix it, just upgrade to a newer version of `R`.

Comment: okay, now the main error you get is in the last line. you may have to restart R to be able to update arules-package

Comment: There are packages that help you keep versions together in projects so that you don't have to upgrade R if you prefer not to upgrade.  In Rstudio there was, and I think there still is, a package called packrat.  But also, Microsoft's distribution of R (called 'Microsoft R Open') does this for you automatically.

Comment: I get the same warning in all tidyverse packages but the next version of R is not yet available for ubuntu 20 it seems. Any ideas why?